# MongoDB Update array in a document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, updates

I try to update arrays of multiple document with this query :

```
db.BusinessRequest.update({"DealTypes": { $exists: true }, "DealTypes.DisplayName": "Minority trade sale" }, {$set:{"DealTypes.$.DisplayName":"Minority"}}, false,true );
```

but when there is a match, it only updates the first row of my array whereas the displayName does not match with the first.

I use IntelliShell of MongoChef software.

My document looks like this :

```
{ 
"_id" : BinData(4, "IKC6QJRGSIywmKTKKRfTHA=="), 
"_t" : "InvestorBusinessRequest", 
"Title" : "Business Request 000000002", 
"DealTypes" : [
    {
        "_id" : "60284B76-1F45-49F3-87B5-5278FF49A304", 
        "DisplayName" : "Majority", 
        "Order" : "001"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "64A52AFE-2FF5-426D-BEA7-8DAE2B0E59A6", 
        "DisplayName" : "Majority trade sale", 
        "Order" : "002"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "C07AE70D-4F62-470D-BF65-06AF93CCEBFA", 
        "DisplayName" : "Minority trade sale", 
        "Order" : "003"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "F5C4390A-CA7D-4AC8-873E-2DC43D7F4158", 
        "DisplayName" : "Equity fund raising", 
        "Order" : "004"
    }
]
```

}

How can I achieve this please ? Thanks in advance

EDIT :
This line works :

```
db.BusinessRequest.update({"DealTypes": { $exists: true }, "DealTypes": { $elemMatch: {"DisplayName": "Majority trade sale"}}}, {$set:{"DealTypes.$.DisplayName":"Majority"}}, false,true );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.BusinessRequest.find().forEach( function(doc) {
  do {
    db.BusinessRequest.update({{"DealTypes": { $exists: true }, "DealTypes.DisplayName": "Minority trade sale" },
                         {$set:{"DealTypes.$.DisplayName":"Minority"}});
  } while (db.getPrevError().n != 0);
})
```

or

You cannot modify multiple array elements in a single update operation. Thus, you'll have to repeat the update in order to migrate documents which need multiple array elements to be modified. You can do this by iterating through each document in the collection, repeatedly applying an update with `$elemMatch` until the document has all of its relevant comments replaced.

```
db.BusinessRequest.update({"DealTypes": { $exists: true }, "DealTypes": { $elemMatch: {"DisplayName": "Majority trade sale"}}}, {$set:{"DealTypes.$.DisplayName":"Majority"}}, false,true );
```

If you need efficiency in the search then I suggest you to normalise schema where each row is kept in separate document.

Comment: I try with $elemMatch and it seems to work : `db.BusinessRequest.update({"DealTypes": { $exists: true }, "DealTypes": { $elemMatch: {"DisplayName": "Majority trade sale"}}}, 
{$set:{"DealTypes.$.DisplayName":"Majority"}}, false,true );`

Comment: If it works ! Then up vote and accept the answer. Let other's also know.

Answer (score 2):

Please execute the following script in your mongo shell :

```
db.BusinessRequest.find({"DealTypes":{$exists:true}}).forEach(function(item)
{

for(i=0;i < item.DealTypes.length;i++)
{
    if(item.DealTypes[i].DisplayName === 'Minority trade sale'){
        item.DealTypes[i].DisplayName = 'Minority';
    }
}
db.BusinessRequest.save(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Last two arguments in your update have a problem.

This is the form of update() method in mongodb

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>
   }
)
```

I believe your update should be like this;

```
db.BusinessRequest.update
( {"DealTypes": { $exists: true }, "DealTypes.DisplayName": "Minority trade sale" }
, {$set:{"DealTypes.$.DisplayName":"Minority"}}
{ upsert : false, multi : true });
```

Comment: Instead of `=`, it should be `:`.

Comment: multi:true do not search in nested fields. So this will not work. Your query will have the same effect as the original one.

Comment: @PratikGujarathi yes, exactly the same effect : still not work

Comment: You can try something similar to the solution which I have posted below.  I don't think that there is any direct way of doing it.